# How can I stop certain keys from being prioritized in a 2D platformer?

Tags: c#, monogame, control

I am currently working on a 2D platformer in Monogame. I have implemented WASD and arrow keys control, but because of the ordering of the if statements, the D key is always executed last if down, making the character flip the wrong direction.

```
if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Left) || Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.A))
{
    if (Velocity.X > -MaxVelocity)
        Velocity.X -= Acceleration.X * time;
    spriteEffect = SpriteEffects.None;
}
else //Deceleration
{
    if (Velocity.X < 0)
        Velocity.X += Acceleration.X * time;
}

if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Right) || Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.D))
{
    if (Velocity.X < MaxVelocity)
        Velocity.X += Acceleration.X * time;
    spriteEffect = SpriteEffects.FlipHorizontally;
}
else //Deceleration
{
    if (Velocity.X > 0)
        Velocity.X -= Acceleration.X * time;
}
```

Is there a way to prioritize the key that is pressed last, as well as only performing one every update cycle?

Answer (score 1):

Have the key pressed specify a target velocity then use that value to determine the direction facing and acceleration.

```
float targetVel = 0.0f;
// accumulate the user input
if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Left) || Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.A))
{
    targetVel -= MaxVelocity;
}
if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Right) || Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.D))
{
    targetVel += MaxVelocity;
}

// only change movement direction if a single directional key is pressed
if (targetVel != 0.0f) {
    spriteEffect = targetVel > 0 ? SpriteEffects.FlipHorizontally : SpriteEffects.None;
}

if (Math.Abs(targetVel - Velocity.X) <= Acceleration.X * time) {
    // if accelerating would move past the target velocity, then just set it directly
    Velocity.X = targetVel;
} else {
    // Move the velocity towards the target velocity
    Velocity.X += Accleration.X * time * Math.Sign(targetVel - Velocity.X);
}
```